# How to configure HikariCP with EclipseLink

Tags: java, playframework, eclipselink, hikaricp

I am migrating our application from Play Framework 2.3.x to 2.4.x. In 2.4.x, the Play Framework uses HikariCP as its connection provider. Any suggestions on how to use HikariCP with EclipseLink?

On the HikariCP, there is only a configuration for Hibernate:
https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Hibernate4

How could I do the same in EclipseLink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looked at the Play documentation [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJPA). From what the framework specifies , looks like you can choose a JPA of your choice in which case it will be EclipseLink. From the understanding that i get , based on the HikariCP configuration you have , the PersistenceUnit will automatically be injected into your code so that the right DS provider is picked up and used during execution.

Out of curiosity , i referred this [question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526654/how-to-use-apache-commons-dbcp-with-eclipselink-jpa-and-tomcat-7-x) answer as well , it is extremely well written and seems to specify that once the right DS is looked up or injected , Eclipse link will use that for connectivity.